# how to redirect two domains to the same tomcat server in a secure network on windows

Tags: java, tomcat7

My tomcat server is running on amazon. I have 2  different domains(https://app.test.com and https://www.app.testpro.com) which I would like to redirect to the same tomcat server instance

Answer (score 0):

If this is just for testing purposes you can edit your [local hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29#Location_in_the_file_system) to achieve this. If you want to configure a production system then you need to change the DNS records for these domains to point to the IP of your Amazon host.

Comment: no this is not for testing purpose .we are using this if our first domain is not working  or on maintenance than we redirect our users to another domain ..